# Upload file using requests module in python is not working (the code generated by Postman)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Am trying to upload a file using requests module in Python.Am able to do it successfully through postman.
The Python-request code generated by Postman is as follows

```
    import requests

url = "https://10.64.17.9:8501/api/category/qa_cat/document/"

payload = {}
files = [
  ('pdf_file', open('/C:/Users/sajina.pm/Documents/Test_Data/QAset/Automation_data/HeliumStudio.pdf','rb'))
]
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJlN0ttUWRWTXdxaXZKcHdZc1piM3Jsc1ZUUUZqcG5HY3JGcGNMT2E5cW5JIn0.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.FDC7a5psIduxPhfDGvAcywHdG3GcSENGm7rwghnyKIoFmRbDDZLqQ7S-PmydyQmETHTcObooBXtWwQpKO_AKCtCo-nRYeVoQT051KC_nY1Ct23phSG07zbeQbZaiYFl0Pra52t5B-tPhktOWfGgo26-qhRw97uyV5XaWHD9ywQqnmYHJwrKstgFuERGY8KCh9gQumhcXDe5b6Z28R-TOcgMiNswPuCn_V3ETk4YTkX7Q7XXRThl_hQ1x5SFft5OBFRb6oqMLVxhTw1N67RC0todPxc0A0pnH-sZbbLeKgW0mJWQ-xMIMe7zqVpaIDmCLax66DF9jaxVMO9L3AaPh1A'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload, files = files)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

> The Above code was giving the following error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\KTWS\Newpython\Search\postman.py", line 12, in <module>
    ('pdf_file', open('/C:/Users/sajina.pm/Documents/Test_Data/QAset/Automation_data/HeliumStudio.pdf','rb'))
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/C:/Users/sajina.pm/Documents/Test_Data/QAset/Automation_data/HeliumStudio.pdf'
```

> I changed

```
`files = [
  ('pdf_file', open('/C:/Users/sajina.pm/Documents/Test_Data/QAset/Automation_data/HeliumStudio.pdf','rb'))`
```

to

```
`files = [
  ('pdf_file', open('C://Users//sajina.pm//Documents//Test_Data//QAset//Automation_data//HeliumStudio.pdf','rb'))`
```

but now am getting the error

```
b'"Wrong file format. Please upload correct file format"\n'
```

Comment: Please read about [ask]. There is no question here... Please give a proper problem statement and what is your current issue. Are you getting an error? if so, post it completely. Wrong output? If so, give us that output with your expected output

Answer (score 0):

You are using a incorrect filename syntax

> open('C://Users//sajina.pm//Documents//Test_Data//QAset//Automation_data//HeliumStudio.pdf','rb')

Correct:

- single slashes: "C:/users/..."
- double backslashes: "C:\\users\\..."
- single backslashes: r"C:\users\..."

You can use the first form because Windows accepts also the slash as path separator.

Comment: I tried all the three and am getting the same error.